# Azure deployment not showing view properly

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment

After uploading my website off visual studio using Azure deployment, my site only shows what looks like my Shared Layout and not my views.

http://ideagendocument.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login

In my local deployment, it shows the login screen as it should. Why would it not be picking up any of my views or css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the reason is that these files are not included in the project.

Can you unload a project and then click "Edit project" and see if references are there?

Comment: as far as i can see, they are all included https://gyazo.com/f5a823d3f2ad4219ac2b4491dcb4d6c2

Comment: what do you mean unload and check references?

Comment: @CaptainCanada Can you send a screenshot of your Content folder?

Comment: @CaptainCanada, I can see that CSS files were loaded successfully. Example: http://ideagendocument.azurewebsites.net/Content/site.css

Comment: So why is my index, nor other Views, loading?

Comment: @CaptainCanada Looks like it is fixed now. Can you confirm?

Comment: Weird, not sure what I changed there but its displaying my views. If I try to register or view anything database related, it gives an error though, assumably this means my database is not connected properly?

Comment: @CaptainCanada, yep it means you have incorrect database configuration.

Comment: Bugger, ill fiddle with that a bit then, see if I can get it going, seems like whatever we did fixed my views though so thanks!